# How to format currency in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How can I format the currency in VB.NET by specifying the symbol to use e.g. £ or $.

I have been using formatcurrency however I can't find a way to change the symbol in front of the value.

Comment: NET should use the symbol for the current culture.  Are you trying to use the symbol for a foreign culture?

Comment: I have set up cultureinfo, how do I specify GBP? , for the usa it is en-us.

Answer (score 5):

Using the legacy VB functions like `FormatCurrency` is limited because they only know the current culture.  `.ToString("C2")` will use the current culture for the symbol and decimal.  To specify a different culture:

```
Dim decV As Decimal = 12.34D

Console.WriteLine("In France: {0}", decV.ToString("C2", New CultureInfo("fr-FR")))
Console.WriteLine("For the Queen! {0}", decV.ToString("C2", New CultureInfo("en-GB")))
Console.WriteLine("When in Rome: {0}", decV.ToString("C2", New CultureInfo("it-IT")))
Console.WriteLine("If you are Hungary: {0}", decV.ToString("C2", New CultureInfo("hu-HU")))
Console.WriteLine("For the US of A: {0}", decV.ToString("C2", New CultureInfo("en-US")))
```

Output:

> In France: 12,34 €
>   For the Queen! £12.34
>   When in Rome: € 12,34
>   If you are Hungary: 12,34 Ft
>   For the US of A: $12.34

[Table of Language Culture Names, Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

You can also have problems converting a foreign currency string to a value because `CDec` only knows how to use the local culture.  You can use `Decimal.TryParse` and specify the incoming culture:

```
' Croatian currency value
Dim strUnkVal = decV.ToString("C2", New CultureInfo("hr-HR"))
Dim myVal As Decimal

' if the string contains a valid value for the specified culture
' it will be in myVal
If Decimal.TryParse(strUnkVal,
                    NumberStyles.Any,
                    New CultureInfo("hr-HR"), myVal) Then
    Console.WriteLine("The round trip: {0}", myVal.ToString("C2"))
End If
```